# Author affiliation and email address in scrartcl class

Tags: koma-script, scrartcl

In the `scrartcl` class, how can one include the author's affiliation, address, and email address?

---

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\maketitle
How do you add author affiliation, address and email address?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please get into the habit to include a small, but compilable test file in your questions.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where you expect it to be printed, you can use, e.g.,

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}% Note: 11pt is the default and therefore not needed.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Note: utf8 us the default of LaTeX >= 2018/04/01.
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{My name\\affiliation\\address\\email}
\maketitle
How do you add author affiliation, address and email address?
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{My name\thanks{affiliation\\address\\email}}
\maketitle
How do you add author affiliation, address and email address?
\end{document}
```

or you can design your title free without using `\maketitle`, or you can use an [additional package](https://ctan.org/topic/titlepage).